# Different speed of theoretically equal queries on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have found a strange speed issue with one of my MySQL queries when run on two different columns, `date_from` vs `date_to`.

The table structure is the following:

```sql
create table if not exists table1 (
    id unsigned int,
    field2 int,
    field3 varchar(32),
    date_from date not null,
    date_to date not null,
    field6 text
);

create unique index idx_uniq_table1 on table1 (id, field2, field3, date_from);
create index idx_table1_id on table1 (id);
create index idx_table1_field2 on table1 (field2);
create index idx_table1_field3 on table1 (field3);
create index idx_table1_date_from on table1 (date_from);
create index idx_table1_date_to on table1 (date_to);
```

When I run this query using `date_from`, execution time is 1.487 seconds:

```sql
select field3, min(date_from) from table1 group by field3;
```

When I run this other query using `date_to`, execution time is 13.804 seconds, almost 10 times slower:

```sql
select field3, max(date_to) from table1 group by field3;
```

Both columns are `NOT NULL`, so there are no empty values.

The table has ~7M rows.

The only difference that I see between these two columns is that `date_from` appears in the unique index but, as far as I know, that should't make a difference if not filtering by all four columns in the index.

Am I missing anything?

This is the explain of the `date_from` column:

```json
{
    "query_block": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "cost_info": {
        "query_cost": "889148.90"
        },
        "grouping_operation": {
            "using_filesort": false,
            "table": {
                "table_name": "table1",
                "access_type": "index",
                "possible_keys": [
                    "idx_uniq_table1",
                    "idx_table1_id",
                    "idx_table1_field2",
                    "idx_table1_field3",
                    "idx_table1_date_from",
                    "idx_table1_date_to"
                ],
                "key": "idx_table1_field3",
                "used_key_parts": [
                    "field3"
                ],
                "key_length": "130",
                "rows_examined_per_scan": 5952609,
                "rows_produced_per_join": 5952609,
                "filtered": "100.00",
                "using_index": true,
                "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "293888.00",
                    "eval_cost": "595260.90",
                    "prefix_cost": "889148.90",
                    "data_read_per_join": "908M"
                },
                "used_columns": [
                    "id",
                    "field2",
                    "field3",
                    "date_from"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the explain of the `date_to` column:

```json
{
    "query_block": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "cost_info": {
            "query_cost": "889148.90"
        },
        "grouping_operation": {
            "using_filesort": false,
            "table": {
                "table_name": "table1",
                "access_type": "index",
                "possible_keys": [
                    "idx_uniq_table1",
                    "idx_table1_id",
                    "idx_table1_field2",
                    "idx_table1_field3",
                    "idx_table1_date_from",
                    "idx_table1_date_to"
                ],
                "key": "idx_table1_field3",
                "used_key_parts": [
                    "field3"
                ],
                "key_length": "130",
                "rows_examined_per_scan": 5952609,
                "rows_produced_per_join": 5952609,
                "filtered": "100.00",
                "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "293888.00",
                    "eval_cost": "595260.90",
                    "prefix_cost": "889148.90",
                    "data_read_per_join": "908M"
                },
                "used_columns": [
                    "id",
                    "field2",
                    "field3",
                    "date_from",
                    "date_to"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference I see is in `used_columns`, at the end, where one contains `date_to` and the other doesn't.

Comment: Try using `EXPLAIN` to find out which index is used by each query.

Comment: The diference could be because one column has more different values than the other one, so the btree structrure that makes the index is more complex.  The performance depends on the query, the indexes and the values that are in the column

Comment: Show both execution plans.

Comment: If I guess correctly,  (id, field2, field3, date_from) is a big help on the fast speed.  It's using the field3 first, then find the min value of date_from in each subrange in the B-tree.
How about add a similar index (field3, date_to) and then check the other one?

Comment: When you ask for MIN on date_from the system only has to read one index entry.  When you ask for MAX on the date_to the system has to read ALL the index entries to get there.  Posting EXPLAIN SELECT ....  each query will document the work required to provide your answers.

Comment: If you are using 8.0.nn or newer, this URL may be helpful to you, if you have a lot of searches of MAX for date_to column.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109108/how-do-i-create-a-desc-index-in-mysql

Comment: @WilsonHauck - I think both of your statements are incorrect.  The OP does not currently have any index that would allow MIN to "read one".  If there were an appropriate index, the Optimizer is quite willing to reach for the "last" to get MAX.

Comment: Maybe we will see the EXPLAIN's in our lifetime to confirm my suggestions.  The first page of the Question clearly indicates indexes are created.  Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naughty. There is no `PRIMARY KEY`.

Since the "used columns" does not seem to agree with the queries, I don't want to try to explain the timing difference.

Replace the index on `field3` by these two:

```
INDEX(field3, date_from)
INDEX(field3, date_to)
```

Those will speed up your two Selects.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rick's answer about proper index based on what your criteria is...  The reason for the speed difference is that the one index that had both the field3 and date_from, the engine was able to use the data within the actual index instead of having to go to the raw data pages that contain the entire record.  The index that only had the date_to still had to go to every raw data record to get the field3, thus taking the time.

That is why you can utilize covering indexes.  Having each component of data you are looking for to optimize the query.  Not saying you want an index with 20 columns, but in this context of what might be common criteria for filtering is exactly why you do.

Comment: I agree.  "Covering" is good; getting the columns in the optimal order is even better.  For example, rearranging `(id, field2, field3, date_from)` to `(field3, date_from, field2, id)` makes that index better.  (Note how the _first_ column(s) match my recommended index.)